# Netbeans 11.1 Stuck on Finding Feature Screen

Tags: netbeans

I am having trouble making a new Java project using Netbeans 11.1, where Netbeans always gets stuck on the Finding Feature screen. I can't seem to be able to actually create a new Java project without getting stuck on this screen. 
I'm currently using JDK 12.0.2 with Netbeans 11.1.

What can I do to get past this screen to actually creating this project?

**Edit:** When I got to this point a notification popped up saying that there was a NoSuchFileException and that it was looking for the NetBeans files in my downloads folder, when all the NetBeans files are in a different directory. Is there a way to change which directory NetBeans checks for these files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you haven't activated the required plugins hence it's not able to find any feature.

Go to Tools --> Plugins --> Installed and activate whatever you want to use and then try to add new project. it should work :)